# Flask login_required and webpage redirect loop

Tags: flask, openid

I am making a webapp to browse a database, and trying to use OpenID to authenticate. 
When trying to access the results of a database query using the following code, while having logged in, I get the result of a webpage redirect loop.

```
app.route("/results", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required                                     
def results():
    form = Query()
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = Composition(form.query.data).reduced_formula
        data = get_md_summary({"pretty_formula": a})
        return render_template("results.html", md=data)
    return render_template("query.html", form=form)
```

When the login_required decorator is removed, the resulting webpage appears, but this means that anyone that is not authenticated can still access the results if they input the final URL and as a result goes around the login step.
What am I doing wrong? I feel I either don't properly understand the use of login_required or I am using the wrong decorator.

Comment: can you show relevant part of the log output?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your `login_view` is set to be the results page, which is why you get a redirect loop - a user which is not logged in gets redirected to the same page again and again.

Have a look here to understand how to set the view for the login:
https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#customizing-the-login-process